# How to Change My admin URL From https:// to http://

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, https

While i install magento2.2.1 3rd Step 
I enable **use https for magento storefront** and **use https for magento admin**

After Installation i cant view page bcoz https not support in my local machine (WAMP)
So I moved to phpmyadmin and select my database and selct "**core_config_data**" table... Here i change config path url from https to http. 
Now i can view my website..

The problem is i cant access admin url
when i typed **localhost/magento/admin** it was changed to **https://localhost/magento/admin/**

How can i change this configuration via database or php code.

Comment: Is it a clean install or do you have custom data in database?

Comment: clean install @Vulpea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a clean install:

- make backup of database(just in case)
- drop database
- create empty database with your name and permissions so magento can access it
- run install command from console
  e.g

  php bin/magento setup:install 
  --base-url="http://example.co.uk/" 
  --db-host="localhost" 
  --db-name="databasename" 
  --db-user="databaseuser" 
  --db-password="databasepass" 
  --admin-firstname="Yourname" 
  --admin-lastname="Yourname" 
  --admin-email="hello@example.co.uk" 
  --admin-user="admin" 
  --admin-password="setpasswordhere" 
  --language="en_GB" 
  --currency="GBP" 
  --timezone="Europe/London" 
  --use-rewrites="1" 
  --backend-frontname="admin"

More information about install command and it's arguments can be found here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

This will reinstall your database schema with populating it with given parameters.

DO NOT USE THIS UNDER ANY CIRCUMSTANCES IF YOU HAVE CUSTOM DATA IN YOUR DATABASE AS THIS WILL RESULT IN LOSING ABOVE MENTIONED DATA